# Vagrant & Digital Ocean - "Token is required"

Tags: vagrant, digital-ocean, puphpet

I've got a Digital Ocean box setup using PuPHPet & Vagrant & it's been working fine up until just now.

I've just tried to run Vagrant provision, but I'm now getting the error...

```
Digital Ocean Provider:
* Token is required
```

I don't even know where to start debugging this?  Any ideas?

Thanks

Update...

Has anything changed with the API access recently has it, as I checked my account & can't see any active API tokens.

The tokens currently configured are (scrambled, but shown for length indication)...

- clientid: 2b6d90cd548a2c70e8ccfd4846e06603
- apikey: b0f7dae57799d631a1cb200c974ef236

... however I can't see a way of creating tokens in this format from the API Keys page any more?

I can only generate a token that is 64 characters long

Comment: Looks like the new api is explained on the github page but the page on DO is still old.
https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-digitalocean

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned over on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community), by default the DigitalOcean [Apps & API page](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/settings/applications) is showing the new version 2 of the API which only requires an OAuth token, not the Client ID and API keys. You can still reach the [v1 API page that provides those keys here](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/api_access).

The [vagrant-digitalocean plugin](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-digitalocean) recently made a new release that changed to using v2 of the API. So if you are using that, you simply need the single token.

You can check out the [full documentation for the new API here.](https://developers.digitalocean.com/) It looks like [PuPHPet already has an open bug](https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/886) to support the new API.